# Generic method to calculate Euclidean Distance using expressions

Tags: c#, linq, expression, expression-trees

I'd like a method that can calculate the Euclidean distance using expressions and order an IQueryable:

sqrt[(q1 - p1)^2 + (q2 - p2)^2 + ... + (qn - pn)^2]

This is the method signature I've come up with:

```
public static IOrderedQueryable<T> EuclideanDistanceOrder<T>(
    this IQueryable<T> query, IEnumerable<Expression<Func<T, double>>> expressions)
    {
        var orderedQuery = query.OrderBy(i => Math.Sqrt(expressions.Aggregate((total, item) => total + Math.Pow(item, 2))));
        return orderedQuery;
    }
```

I'm not sure what to do with `item` and `total` (since they are `Expression<Func<T, double>>`).
I've tried this a few different ways, including using `Expression.Power` and `Expression.Add`. I've tried defining the expressions to be composed separately:

```
Expression<Func<double, double>> power = i => Math.Pow(i, 2);
Expression<Func<List<Expression<Func<T, double>>>, double>> dist = (items) => Math.Sqrt(items.Sum(power));
```

But I still don't know what to do with `power`.

Is there a better way to approach this?

Comment: I should add that this needs to be able to execute in linq to sql and Entity Framework.

Comment: @AndreCalil now that I look at it again, yeah, it does look a bit like homework, but this is just a hobby project I'm working on for myself...

Comment: @AndreCalil What happens if it's homework ?Even if homework he tried a lot to find solution.

Comment: you want to know what pow function doing ?

Comment: `Math.Pow(i,2)` can be replaced with `i*i`;

Comment: How can I show my appreciation to Rafal and Iridium ? Neither answer really works, but they've helped me a lot!

Answer (score 1):

I haven't been able to test this, but it seems that it ought to work. There's no square-root at the end, but the order should be the same either way.

```
public static IOrderedQueryable<T> EuclideanDistanceOrder<T>(this IQueryable<T> query, IEnumerable<Expression<Func<T, double>>> expressions)
{
    var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "item");
    var seed = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, double>>(Expression.Constant((double)0), parameter);
    return query.OrderBy(expressions.Aggregate(seed, GetAggregateExpression));
}

private static Expression<Func<T, double>> GetAggregateExpression<T>(Expression<Func<T, double>> sum, Expression<Func<T, double>> item)
{
    var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "item");
    return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, double>>(Expression.Add(Expression.Invoke(sum, parameter), Expression.Power(Expression.Invoke(item, parameter), Expression.Constant((double)2))), parameter);
}
```

**Edit:**

Since you can't use `Expression.Invoke()`, you'll need to inline the bodies of the Expressions passed into `EuclideanDistanceOrder`. There doesn't seem to be any "nice" way to do this, so I've written a `Replace` method to do it. I've only implemented `Replace` for some of the more common `Expression` types, hopefully this will be enough to cover your usage, but you may need to implement it for other `Expression` types.

```
public static IOrderedQueryable<T> EuclideanDistanceOrder<T>(this IQueryable<T> query, IEnumerable<Expression<Func<T, double>>> expressions)
{
    var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "item");
    var seed = Expression.Constant((double)0);
    var agg = expressions.Aggregate((Expression)seed, (s, item) => Expression.Add(s, Expression.Power(Replace(item.Body, item.Parameters[0], parameter), Expression.Constant((double)2))));
    return query.OrderBy(Expression.Lambda<Func<T, double>>(agg, parameter));
}

private static Expression Replace(Expression expression, ParameterExpression original, ParameterExpression replacement)
{
    if (expression is BinaryExpression)
    {
        var binaryExpression = (BinaryExpression)expression;
        return Expression.MakeBinary(expression.NodeType, Replace(binaryExpression.Left, original, replacement), Replace(binaryExpression.Right, original, replacement), binaryExpression.IsLiftedToNull, binaryExpression.Method, binaryExpression.Conversion);
    }
    if (expression is ConditionalExpression)
    {
        var conditionalExpression = (ConditionalExpression)expression;
        return Expression.Condition(Replace(conditionalExpression.Test, original, replacement), Replace(conditionalExpression.IfTrue, original, replacement), Replace(conditionalExpression.IfFalse, original, replacement), conditionalExpression.Type);
    }
    if (expression is ConstantExpression)
    {
        return expression;
    }
    if (expression is MemberExpression)
    {
        var memberExpression = (MemberExpression)expression;
        return Expression.MakeMemberAccess(Replace(memberExpression.Expression, original, replacement), memberExpression.Member);
    }
    if (expression is ParameterExpression)
    {
        var parameterExpression = (ParameterExpression)expression;
        return parameterExpression == original ? replacement : parameterExpression;
    }
    if (expression is UnaryExpression)
    {
        var unaryExpression = (UnaryExpression)expression;
        return Expression.MakeUnary(unaryExpression.NodeType, Replace(unaryExpression.Operand, original, replacement), unaryExpression.Type, unaryExpression.Method);
    }
    throw new Exception(string.Format("Unsupported expression type: {0}", expression.NodeType));
}
```

So if for example, our input expressions are:

```
p => p.X1 - p.X2
p => p.Y1 - p.Y2
```

The original implementation would've constructed:

```
i => 0 + expressions[0](i) ^ 2 + expressions[1](i) ^ 2
```

The new implementation takes the original expression, and replaces the input parameter (`p` in the above) with the parameter that will be passed to the final lambda (`i`), and uses the body of the expression directly in the output:

```
i => 0 + (i.X1 - i.X2) ^ 2 + (i.Y1 - i.Y2) ^ 2
```

Comment: The minor errors are that Constants should be double not int. Then I got ArgumentExection "At least one object must implement IComparable."

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion. Unfortunately, Expression.Invoke is not supported by Linq to Entities.

Comment: @cofiem I've edited the answer to provide an Invoke-free implementation. See how that works for you.

Comment: @Iridium Thanks very much for your help. I've tried this out, and there are indeed expressions that I'll need to implement. The first one that throw an exception was `NodeType` = `Call`. I'm thinking that what I'm trying to do may not be possible without a lot of work. Perhaps I should be thinking about a less generic way to do this?

Comment: Going for a generic route is probably going to be useful if you have many distinct sets of expressions you want to use for the Euclidean ordering, or you're using it for many different types "T". That's something you'll need to answer though. If you do decide to continue with this route, it should be easy enough to add a replacement handler for Call if you need to.

Answer (score 1):

To get it working with EF or LinqToSQL you would have to pass all information as Expressions even property accessors for P and Q. So that is why I have modified your method declaration:

```
public static class Extension
{
    public static IOrderedQueryable<T> EuclideanDistanceOrder<T>(
        this IQueryable<T> query, 
        IEnumerable<Expression<Func<T, double>>> pExpressions, 
        IEnumerable<Expression<Func<T, double>>> qExpressions)
    {
        var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));
        var pBodies = pExpressions
            .Select(x => ReplaceParameter(x.Body, parameter))
            .ToArray();

        var qBodies = qExpressions
            .Select(x => ReplaceParameter(x.Body, parameter))
            .ToArray();

        var distances = pBodies
            .Select((x, i) => CreateDistance(x, qBodies[i]))
            .ToArray();

        var squers = distances
            .Select(x => CreateSquerExpression(x))
            .ToArray();

        var sum = squers.First();
        for (int i = 1; i < squers.Count(); i++)
        {
            sum = Expression.Add(sum, squers[i]);
        }
        var funcExpression = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, double>>(sum, parameter);
        //the sqrt is irrelevant to order of this sequence
        return query.OrderBy(funcExpression);
    }

    private static Expression CreateDistance(Expression p, Expression q)
    {
        return Expression.Subtract(q, p);
    }

    private static Expression CreateSquerExpression(Expression x)
    {
        var method = typeof(Math).GetMethod("Pow", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public);
        return Expression.Call(method, x, Expression.Constant(2.0));
    }

    private static Expression ReplaceParameter(Expression expression, ParameterExpression parameter)
    {
        var unaryExpression = expression as UnaryExpression;
        MemberExpression memberExpression;
        if (unaryExpression != null)
        {
            memberExpression = unaryExpression.Operand as MemberExpression;
        }
        else
        {
            memberExpression = expression as MemberExpression;
        }

        if (memberExpression == null)
            throw new NotImplementedException();

        if (!(memberExpression.Expression is ParameterExpression) || !(memberExpression.Member is PropertyInfo))
            throw new NotImplementedException();

        return Expression.Property(parameter, (PropertyInfo)memberExpression.Member);
    }
}
```

While invoking like this:

```
    var list = new[]{ new Item
    {
        P1 = 0,
        Q1 = 0,
        P2 = 3,
        Q2 = 1,
    },
    new Item
    {
        P1 = 0,
        Q1 = 0,
        P2 = 2,
        Q2 = 1,
    }
};

var query = list.AsQueryable();

var result = query.EuclideanDistanceOrder(new Expression<Func<Item, double>>[]{
    x => x.P1,
    x => x.P2
},
new Expression<Func<Item, double>>[]{
    x => x.Q1,
    x => x.Q2
}).ToArray();

internal class Item
{
    public double P1 { get; set; }
    public double Q1 { get; set; }
    public double P2 { get; set; }
    public double Q2 { get; set; }
}
```

It works for liq to objects. I'm only not sure if EF or linqtoSql will map `Math.Power` method to sql. If not it is easy enough to change to multiplication.

Comment: THanks very much. When I run this, I get Expression of type 'System.Func`2[<Type,>System.Double]' cannot be used for parameter of type 'System.Double' of method 'Double Pow(Double, Double)'

Comment: I'm executing it on linq to objects and it works fine. I don't understand why it would throw for you. As parameter of Pow function I pass distance which is of type `SimpleBinaryExpression` and the other argument is `ConstantExpression`. Maybe it is linq to objects that is failing try changing `CreateSquerExpression` body to `return Expression.Multiply(x, x);`

Comment: Thanks for the response. I've changed some things around, and now I get a NotImplementedException due to `unaryExpression.Operand` not being a `MemberExpression` (so `memberExpression` is null). Perhaps I need to do this in a some other way?

Comment: The idea behind `ReplaceParameter` method is to find all `ParameterExprsion` instances and replace them with given parameter. This is needed because we create single method with one parameter based on collection of methods. The more sophisticated methods are given as input the more complex this method must be. Just debug to see what expression you have and traverse its `Left`, `Right` or whatever it has. The easiest way to do this is to use recurrence it will be OK for small trees. Basically Iridium showed you exactly what you need to do.